# javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, jboss

I have a junit class to test my DAO's methods. However, after run, this error appear: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial .

The conection was created out of the container and pass it as argument. What could I do!

This is the class' stretch:

```
   ...
        @Test
        public void pesquisarPorIdComConexao() throws SQLException {
            TabCNAEAlvaraAutomaticoDAO DAO = new TabCNAEAlvaraAutomaticoDAO();
            TabCNAEAlvaAutomaticoDto dto = new TabCNAEAlvaAutomaticoDto();
            Connection connection = null;
            try {
                connection = abrir();
                connection.setAutoCommit(false);
                dto = DAO.pesquisarPorId(Long.valueOf("12"), connection);
                assertEquals("Método - pesquisarPorId com Conexão - Com sucesso!",dto != null,dto);

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                fail("Falha no método pesquisarPorId com Conexão ");

            } finally {
                connection.close();
                System.out.println("finalizei");
            }
        }
 // ================== Métodos Auxiliares ======================

    /**
     * Cria uma nova Conexão.
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    private static Connection abrir() throws Exception {
        Connection conexao = null;
        Class.forName(DRIVER); // Registrar o driver
        conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USUARIO, SENHA); // Capturar a conexão
        return conexao; // Retorna a conexao aberta
    }

    /**
     * Popula dados para métodos de do DAO.
     * @param dto
     */
    private void carregaDto (TabCNAEAlvaAutomaticoDto dto){
        dto.settCnpjInstRegra("05055009000113");
        dto.settCodCbo("");
        dto.settCodCnae("3314717");
        dto.settFlagCBOCNAE("1");
        dto.settStatus(1);
        dto.settIdSec(Long.valueOf("12"));
    }
```

Comment: There's no JNDI context when you run outside a Java EE app server.  You need to provide data sources to your JUnit test by other means.  Applet?  Nobody uses applets anymore.  That's 1995 technology.

Comment: Could you paste your DAO's code and also the full stack trace of your exception ? Also you should use try with exceptions because you might get  a NPE if your connection isn't created in your finally block